# When switching between forms pictures seem to have trouble loading

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I switch between two forms with pictures and textboxes there are these ugly black backgrounds that appears for a split second before it all loads. I run the forms with this code in the onLoad

```
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
```

I have also removed the control buttons so it's a fullscreen experience. I have searched around on google and stackoverflow but have not found a solution. Here is a gif of the problem: [GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/dfadb37c39648bfaf3116c5a1c51bb01.mp4)

EDIT1:

As requested by A Friend inn the comments here is the codes behind the buttons.

```
 Private Sub btnReg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReg.Click
    registrerSide.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

And

```
 Private Sub btnAvbryt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAvbryt.Click
    LoginWindow.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The current information is good and the gif is helpful too! It would be great if you could also add the code where you create the forms, display them, etc.

Comment: I have done it all inn the Designer, not sure if you want me to paste the code from the form.Designer.vb ?

Comment: The code when you click the Register button, and the relevant form constructor/load/shown code, etc.

Comment: @AFriend edited the post so it has the code!